# something about the dealloc method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have a root controller MyViewController, with an instance variable named var1.  I assign a value to var1, yet I don't release it in dealloc method.

My question is what is it going to happen after the app exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From dealloc [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)...

> Important: Note that when an application terminates, objects may
>   not be sent a dealloc message since the process’s memory is
>   automatically cleared on exit—it is more efficient simply to allow the
>   operating system to clean up resources than to invoke all the memory
>   management methods. For this and other reasons, you should not manage
>   scarce resources in dealloc—see “Object Ownership and Disposal” in
>   Memory Management Programming Guide for more details.

Comment: So can I say that if an instance of a class always exist on the app's life time, it's ok not to release the instance variables of the class in the dealloc method?Because no matter what, the operating system would do that for us.

Answer (score 4):

The memory is reclaimed when the app exits. However, keep in mind your app is not exiting in recent versions of iOS unless the user terminates it or the OS terminates it for using too much memory.